# I am pregnant "for" or "with" my second child?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of these is the correct phrasing ?

> "I am pregnant **for** my second child"

or

> "I am pregnant **with** my second child"

Comment: You are pregnant "with" your second child.

Comment: Or *I am pregnant for the second time*.

Comment: Or *it is my second pregnancy.*

Comment: If you use "for" it sounds like a surrogate pregnancy.

Comment: There is literally no other preposition in use besides with: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pregnant+*_ADP+second&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpregnant%20with_ADP%20second%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

"With" is the correct word to use in the example sentence given.  In the case of a pregnant human mother, it is said "she is [with child](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-child)."  For other animals it is correct to say "[with young](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with-young)."

Comment: *With child* was standard many decades ago (as a prissy way of saying *pregnant*). I doubt very much if anyone would use it today.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Heard it being used on the TV show Psych just yesterday.